# Get Values from single column based on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have query and I can display values based on condition in SQL. But how can write C# LINQ query is my question.

```
SELECT Value 
FROM db.table 
WHERE xxId = 1 AND YYid = 2 AND IsActive = '1' AND IsDeleted = '0'
```

Result

```
NNNN
MMMM
TTTT
VVVV
LLLL
```

I need same query in LINQ C#

```
var results = db.table
                .Select(a => a.xxid == xxid && a.yyid == id && 
                             a.IsActive && !a.IsDeleted).value;
```

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for edit  my question i am a student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = db.table
             .Where(a => a.xxid == xxid && a.yyid == id && a.IsActive && !a.IsDeleted)
             .Select(a => a.value)
             .ToList();
```